# How can i use group by and order by together in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

```
select t.spdi_application_id,t.spdi_attribute_id, t.spdi_attribute_value 
from schm_sp.spe_service_appl_cert_details t 
where spdi_attribute_id in(395,263,397,396,75) 
GROUP BY spdi_application_id 
ORDER BY spdi_application_id,spdi_attribute_id
```

i am using this command but i am getting error as follows

```
ERROR:  column "t.spdi_attribute_id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: select t.spdi_application_id,t.spdi_attribute_id, t.spdi_att...
                                     ^

********** Error **********

ERROR: column "t.spdi_attribute_id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
SQL state: 42803
Character: 30
```

How ever without group by it works fine with no errors.

Comment: Why do you use GROUP BY anyway? You don't use any aggregate functions. And you have to mention ALL columns that are selected without the usage of an aggregate function, in the GROUP BY. That's what the database is telling you, your GROUP BY is wrong. It has nothing to do with the ORDER BY, without the ORDER BY you get the same error message.

Comment: If I want to see the underlying values for non-grouped columns without aggregation, I usually use `string_agg` or `array_agg`, which will give you non-atomic columns.

Answer (score 3):

When you do a "group by" you are flattening down the rows by a column or columns.  For the columns not in the "group by" you need to tell Postgres how it should merge a column's data using an aggregate function.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html

In your case you need to tell Postgres how to flatten the columns attribute_id and attribute_value when there are multiple rows with the same application_id.  Should it return the max() id and value?  Should it sum() them together?  Should it concat them into an array of values?  Should it return the average value?

```
select app_id, max(attr_id) as max_attr_id from foo group by app_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to use same columns in order by as those are in Group By. I also faced this issue and it got resolved by doing this. Therefore, the corrected SQL query for you is as below :

select t.spdi_application_id,t.spdi_attribute_id, t.spdi_attribute_value
from schm_sp.spe_service_appl_cert_details t
where spdi_attribute_id in(395,263,397,396,75)
GROUP BY spdi_application_id
ORDER BY spdi_application_id